# Call Python tasks from Golang

Tags: python, go, concurrency, server, microservices

I have been building big data application for stock market analysis. About 5TB of records per day. I use Golang for data transformation/calculation and saving in Cassandra/MySQL. But Python has very good libraries for data analysis Pandas, Spark and etc., but there is no easy way for multicore processing and takes a lot of time.

So, I want to call python data analysis tasks concurrently in Golang. One way is to execute command line task directly, but I think there should be more scalable solution. Maybe there is library for communication between Golang and Python. I thought maybe I should create multiple servers of Python Flask and give tasks to them. Speed is important, but I can sacrifice some of it for concise solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Splitting your app into multiple servers, as you've suggested, carries some trade-offs.

On the plus side, splitting it up provides you with more flexibility in terms of load balancing. In other words, if your flask servers are overburdened, you can always spin a few more and scale horizontally with a load-balancer. Of course this assumes that whatever it is you're doing on those flask server can be done in parallel (depends on your actual business logic).

It also offers high-availability: you eliminate one potential single-point-of-failure.

However, this 'microservice' approach does incur some overheads

- more code to write, since now you're writing 2 kinds of servers
- some network overhead, since now you're communicating over the network as opposed to function calls.
- more machines to spin (although you could run everything in containers and they could all be on the same machine, if you dont need the extra processing power)

You could consider using [google-protobuff](https://github.com/google/protobuf) to serialize/de serialize the messages. its language-agnostic and saves some of the network overhead. its not as easy as sending json, but if efficiency is paramount, it might be worth the trouble. Plus it's supported in both python and go.